# Update an MySql Table by Values

Tags: mysql

i have a Problem with Updating an existent Database Row, i would like to Update the row with the products_weight, this row has actually no data insert.

Now i have an Export of my old Database with the row "product_Modell and product_weight", and i would like to update the products_weight by SQL Update command, like this:

when products_model (SQL Table products) = products_model (The VALUE in my code) then Update the Value "products_weight from the Value of my code.

It don´t work. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

best regards

I have tried this one:

```
UPDATE xt_products products_model, products_weight WHERE products_model=products_model VALUES
('109', '0.0000'),
('109-01', '0.0000'),
('109-02', '0.1000'),
('109-03', '11.0000'),
('109-04', '0.0000'),
('109-05', '0.0000'),
('109-06', '0.0000'),
('109-07', '0.0000');
```

Comment: I don't understand, if (as you say _i would like to Update the row with the products_weight, this row has actually no data insert_) the row has no data, it doesn't exist, so you cannot UPDATE something that doesn't exist. You should INSERT it

Comment: if there are no data inserted how can you evaluate the condition about the product model in your where statement? isn't it empty? provide some sample data about your table before updating

Comment: Anyway, your UPDATE sintax is wrong, it should be **UPDATE table SET col_name = value WHERE condition** something like this

Comment: Sorry here is my Answer, about it in the row products_weight exists in the Database, but the value is 0 by all products_model. i would be update the products_weight by the second value in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on my understanding, you have a table from an old database that you wish to import to a new database? if so, you can use this.

```
INSERT INTO `OldDatabase`.`table1` (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM `NewDatabase`.`table1`
WHERE condition;
```

Ofcourse the `columns1`,`columns2`,etc.. count should match.

If you want to update values by a matching ID

```
UPDATE  `NewDatabase`.`table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `OldDatabase`.`table1` t2
ON t2.`products_model`= t1.`products_model`
SET t1.products_weight = t2.products_weight
```

Comment: I have the Values of the old Database in an SQL Dump.

like this:

``
INSERT INTO `xt_products` (`products_model`, `products_weight`) VALUES
('109', '0.0000'),
('109-01', '0.0000'),
('109-02', '0.1000'),
('109-03', '11.0000'),
('109-04', '0.0000'),
('109-05', '0.0000'),
('109-06', '0.0000'),
('109-07', '0.0000'),
('158', '0.0000'),
('158-01', '0.0000'),
('158-02', '0.0000'),
('158-03', '0.0000'),
('158-04', '0.0000'),
('158-05', '11.0000'),
('158-06', '0.0000'),
('158-07', '0.0000'),
('158-08', '0.0000');
``

Comment: ok, now u want to convert this into a new table? if so, why don't you just copy-paste the whole lot, and change the table and column name to match the new table?

Comment: tell me the (1) New table Name... (2) The Columns In the New Table

Comment: In the new Database the Same VALUES are insert, but the weight is by all articles 0. now i would update the new Database with the values of this dump, checking the value procuts_model by old and new database, if this match, then update the weight by the right products_model

Comment: When u say `article` you meant `product_model`?

Comment: the database in new database is like the same as old database, only updateing the row product_weight from old database to new database by using update skript in sql browser

Comment: yes the product_model is the same in old and new database... if this number matches then update the weight from old database weight value.

Comment: Ok.... If you say everything is identical, and both databases exists. use my update query in the solution.

Comment: ok thanks, but where i should insert the values of old database, like this:
``VALUES ('109', '0.0000'), ('109-01', '0.0000'), ('109-02', '0.1000'), ('109-03', '11.0000'), ('109-04', '0.0000'), ('109-05', '0.0000'), ('109-06', '0.0000'), ('109-07', '0.0000'), ('158', '0.0000'), ('158-01', '0.0000'), ('158-02', '0.0000'), ('158-03', '0.0000'), ('158-04', '0.0000'), ('158-05', '11.0000'), ('158-06', '0.0000'), ('158-07', '0.0000'), ('158-08', '0.0000'); ``

Comment: The `Update Statement` would automatically set the data from the old database into the new database. provided that you have the old database in your server. Is your old database in your server still existent?

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Dump:**

Edit your dump file (have a backup of your dump file)

Find --> `xt_products` and replace into --> `xt_products_old`

Then save the dump file

**In MySQL:**

Run the below query

`CREATE TABLE xt_products_old like xt_products;`

Then Import the sql Dump(Edited)

**OR**

If your dump has only the below data as mentioned

```
INSERT INTO xt_products (products_model, products_weight) 
VALUES ('109', '0.0000'), ('109-01', '0.0000'), ('109-02', '0.1000'),
 ('109-03', '11.0000'), ('109-04', '0.0000'), ('109-05', '0.0000'),
 ('109-06', '0.0000'), ('109-07', '0.0000'), ('158', '0.0000'),
 ('158-01', '0.0000'), ('158-02', '0.0000'), ('158-03', '0.0000'),
 ('158-04', '0.0000'), ('158-05', '11.0000'), ('158-06', '0.0000'),
 ('158-07', '0.0000'), ('158-08', '0.0000');
```

Just run the below query

```
INSERT INTO xt_products_old (products_model, products_weight) 
VALUES ('109', '0.0000'), ('109-01', '0.0000'), ('109-02', '0.1000'),
 ('109-03', '11.0000'), ('109-04', '0.0000'), ('109-05', '0.0000'),
 ('109-06', '0.0000'), ('109-07', '0.0000'), ('158', '0.0000'),
 ('158-01', '0.0000'), ('158-02', '0.0000'), ('158-03', '0.0000'),
 ('158-04', '0.0000'), ('158-05', '11.0000'), ('158-06', '0.0000'),
 ('158-07', '0.0000'), ('158-08', '0.0000');
```

Now run `update` query:

```
UPDATE 
xt_products n
JOIN xt_products_old o on n.products_model=o.products_model
SET n.products_weight=o.products_weight;
```

On success just drop the table `xt_products_old`

`DROP TABLE xt_products_old;`